Jira Server REST API v2 Python Copying Dashboard
I am using this library to try and automate the process of copying/creating a new dashboard with gadgets. Jira Python Library
Here is my code
from jira import JIRA
from jira.resources import Dashboard, DashboardGadget, DashboardItemProperty, DashboardItemPropertyKey
from jira.client import JIRA


# Connect to JIRA
jira_options = {'server': 'https://your-jira-instance'}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=('your_username', 'your_password'))

dashboards = jira.dashboards(filter = 'my')
print(len(dashboards))

# Print the dashboards
for dashboard in dashboards:
    print(f"Dashboard ID: {dashboard.id}, Name: {dashboard.name}") 
#Viewing existing dashboard runs successfully 

# Define the dashboard ID to copy and new dashboard details
source_dashboard_id = '11111'
new_dashboard_name = 'Python Dashboard'
new_dashboard_description = 'Check Automation'

# Copy the dashboard
new_dashboard = jira.copy_dashboard(id=source_dashboard_id,
                                    name=new_dashboard_name,
                                    description=new_dashboard_description)

# Verify the dashboard creation
if new_dashboard:
    print(f"New dashboard created with ID: {new_dashboard.id}")
    print(f"Name: {new_dashboard.name}")
    print(f"Description: {new_dashboard.description}")
else:
    print("Dashboard copy failed.")


The variable new_dashboard simply returns None. If I run the function separate from the library I get a 405 error.
I have also tried the code from this post with a similar issue - viewing the dashboard is fine but copying always gives an error.
Copy Dashboard Stackoverflow
I'm beginning to suspect that copying dashboard is not supported in Jira server. Could someone please confirm if this has been true in your experience?
REST API
